# JQuery calls not calling the from the correct <div>

Tags: jquery, python, html, ajax, flask

I want to be able to call different templates into my different div's but when I click the buttons it only calls newyork.html whether I press the New York or Miami button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
    $("#england").load("/hello");

});
$("buttonfra").click(function(){
    $("#france").load("/hello2");

});

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button>New York</button>
<button id="buttonfra">Miami</button>

<div id = "england">
<h2>London</h2>
<p>London is the capital of England. It is the most populous city in the     United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
</div>

<div id="france">
<h2>Paris</h2>
<p>Paris is the capital and most populous city of France.</p>
</div>

<script>
var x = $("li").text();
console.log(x);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the python script that i'm running:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)  

@app.route('/hello/')
@app.route('/hello/<name>')
def hello(name=None):
return render_template('newyork.html', name=name) 

def hello2(name=None):
return render_template('miami.html', name=name) 


@app.route('/')
def test():
return "test"

if __name__ == "__main__":     
app.run()
```

And here is my newyork.html template:

```
<!doctype html> <title>New York City</title> {% if name %}   <h1>Hello {{ name }}!</h1> {% else %}   
<h1>New York City!</h1>
<p>New York City comprises 5 boroughs sitting where the Hudson River meets the Atlantic Ocean.</p>
<p>At its core is Manhattan, a densely populated borough that’s among the world’s major commercial, financial and cultural centers. </p>
<p>Its iconic sites include skyscrapers such as the Empire State Building and sprawling Central Park. Broadway theater is staged in neon-lit Times Square. </p>{% endif %}
```

And my miami.html template:

```
<!doctype html> <title>Miami</title> {% if name %}   <h1>Hello {{ name }}!</h1> {% else %}  
<h1>Miami!</h1>
<p>Miami is an international city at Florida's southeastern tip. Its Cuban influence is reflected in the cafes and cigar shops that line Calle Ocho in Little Havana.</p>
<p>On barrier islands across the turquoise waters of Biscayne Bay is Miami Beach, home to South Beach.</p>
<p>This glamorous neighborhood is famed for its colorful art deco buildings, white sand, surfside hotels and trendsetting nightclubs.</p>{% endif %}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [jQuery's selector rules](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). With `$("button").click(...)` you bind the click event for each button element, but the `$("buttonfra").click(...)` binding is not working because you don't have a `buttonfra` element, it's an id attribute: `<button id="buttonfra">`.

The simplest way to solve this is to use id attributes at both buttons:

```
<button id="buttonny">New York</button>
<button id="buttonfra">Miami</button>
```

And the jQuery bindings for them:

```
$("#buttonny").click(function(){
    $("#england").load("/hello");    
});
$("#buttonfra").click(function(){
    $("#france").load("/hello2");    
});
```